# PHP Fatal error: Trying to compare `if ($row['distance_name']==$split($i)`

Tags: php

I am trying to compare $split variable deinfed at top of the php code($split1, $split2) with database record `if ($row['distance_name']==$split($i)`

and it throws error `PHP Fatal error:  Function name must be a string`

```
   <?
    $split1="1";
    $split2="2";

$plan_sql="select distance_name from mytablename";

$plan_res=mysqli_query($con,$plan_sql);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($plan_res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $result[] = $row;
};


        for ($i=1; $i <= 8; $i++):?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Split <?php echo $i; ?></label>
            <select class="form-control required" name='distance[]' id='distance' >
                <option value="">Select Distance</option>
                <?php foreach ($result as $row):?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $row['distance_name'];?>" <?php if ($row['distance_name']==$split($i)) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $row['distance_name'];?></option>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: what is `$split()`?

Comment: @FastSnail $split is the varaible defined at top so $split1, $split2

Comment: so why you use `()` for a variable.i don't know whta you a trying to do

Comment: `$split1` and `$split2` are variables; `$split` is not a variable; but you're using it as though it was a variable containing a function with those  brackets `$split()` Perhaps you should consider using an array rather than numbered variables

Comment: Since its a for loop it should compare $split1 ...$split8 to $row['distance_name'];?> if it matches show selected

Comment: @MarkBaker I tried using $split.$i but it doesnt compare

Comment: Variable variables are rarely a good idea; because it's so hard to read and understand code that uses them: Use an array instead - `$split = []; $split[1]="1";
$split[2]="2"; etc` to define an array; then compare using `if ($row['distance_name']==$split[$i])`

Comment: @MarkBaker Unfortunately I have to use variable in this case as this code is small part of a 1000 lines php code

Comment: So why can that variable not be an array? The size of your code doesn't preclude that; and it would be better in a whole host of different ways than using variable variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What's Wrong

You're trying to use a "variable variable" by building a variable name from two pieces, `split` and `$i`. This is not usually the best way to do things, and you're doing it incorrectly.

`$split($i)` doesn't mean "the variable named 'split and the value of `$i`.'" It means, "take a variable named `$split`, treat its value as a function, and call that function with a parameter of `$i`."

## How to "Fix" It

If you really want to use variable variables, your syntax needs to be this:

```
${'split' . $i}
```

**Again, this is a bad idea. You really should use an array instead.**

## How to Do It a Better Way

Use an array, as in

```
$split[1] = 1;
$split[2] = 2;
...
```

Then refer to the values as `$split[$i]` for whatever (valid) values of `$i`.